# calling variable in multiple functions javascript angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller file

```
angular.module('IpadAppApp')
    .controller('Mortgage_LoanCtrl', function ($location, $scope, $http, $modal) {

    var loans, loandatarray, loandata, params, passParams;

    $scope.paramsData = function() {
         params = {
           land_type: (!!filter.loan_type.value? filter.loan_type.value : 'Residential'),
         property: (!!filter.property_value.value? filter.property_value.value : 500000),
         finance_margin: (!!filter.margin_finance.value? filter.margin_finance.value : 90),
         tenure: (!!filter.tenure.value? filter.tenure.value : 20),
         rate_type: (!!filter.rate_type.value? filter.rate_type.value : 'Floating and fixed interest'),
         flexi: (!!filter.full_non_flexi.value? filter.full_non_flexi.value : 'Full flexi and non full flexi loan'),
         islamic: (!!filter.conventional_islamic.value? filter.conventional_islamic.value : 'Islamic and Conventional'),
         sort_by: $scope.getActiveColumn('table.packages'),
         sort_direction: $scope.getSortDirection('table.packages'),
         lock_in: (!!filter.lock_period.value? filter.lock_period.value : 'Show all')
       };
       return params;
     };

   $scope.homeloandata = function() {

        $scope.paramsData();
        passParams = params;
        passParams = JSON.stringify(passParams).replace(/:/g,'=').replace(/"/g,'').replace(/,/g,'&').replace(/{/g,'').replace(/}/g,'').replace(/ /g,'+');   
    };

   $scope.submit_info = function() {
     console.log(passParams);
   };
});
```

The problem is when i ask for the passParams variable in homeloandata it returns perfectly.

But when i ask for the data in submit_info, it returns undefined.

Does anyone know why? I want to return the data in passParams in submit_info.

Comment: `passParams` is only being set in `homeloandata()`. Is `homeloandata()` called?

Comment: You need to call homeloandata() before submit_info.

Comment: homeloandata() is already been called by another function. @WayneEllery

Comment: $scope.update_result = function() {
    console.log('getting input data');
    $scope.paramsData();
    $scope.homeloandata();
   };

Comment: that function calls paramsData and homeloandata()

Comment: that's repitition isnt it since d passParams is defined in a global scope already/

Comment: It's declared but not set. It only gets set in homelonedata